# Sort TListBox Items Alphabetically in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, sorting, delphi-7, tlistbox

I am attempting to trigger a sort on the items within a *TListBox* control after adding/editing entries.

I see that there is a *Sorted* property which I've set to true, however, this doesn't dynamically sort the *ListBox* every time I make a change to the contents. There doesn't seem to be any *Sort* procedure or function available and calling *Update* or *Refresh* does not have the desired effect.

I've reached the stage where I'm considering pulling the contents of the *ListBox* into a *TStringList* object, sorting that and then putting everything back into the *ListBox* again. This seems a bit insane though, surely I am overlooking some better method.

Here's an example of changing an existing item:

```
 myListBox.Items[myIndex] := newString; // Update Text
 myListBox.Items.Objects[myIndex] := TObject(my_object); // Update associated object
```

I would expect the control to update to keep things sorted alphabetically but it doesn't.

Comment: `ListBox.Sorted := True` works fine here, and just as you intend. You'll need to show code.

Comment: You can't change the item by it's position like this, you must remove and add again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sorted property of a list box is actually backed by the Win32 list box style `LBS_SORT`. That will sort the list box when a new item is added. But it will not do so when an existing item is modified.

So the easy way to work around this is to set `Sorted` to `True`, then, instead of modifying existing values, remove the old value and add the new one. So your code would become:

```
myListBox.Items.Delete(myIndex);
myListBox.Items.AddObject(newString, TObject(my_object));
```

And if you think about it, your code would have been doomed to failure if the list box behaved the way you expected it to. Because after you modified the text of the item, if the list was re-sorted then `myIndex` would no longer refer to the same item.

Comment: Doesn't "Delete" cause memory leak? if there is an object associated?

Comment: Thanks David, this method works. I already had plans for recalculating myIndex but this is more efficient.

Comment: I expect that the underlying control uses insertion sort and hence that behaviour is reflected on to you. In any case I think the approach here does all you need.

Comment: @MarcusAdams You've no way to know that. The object may be owned by something else.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, oh, that was Mattheus that commented, not the OP, I'll edit the comment.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas, you would have the same memory leak in the original code. Replacing an object (pointer) doesn't free the previous one. Yes, you may want to do something with the object before you delete.